# Update custom control in LightSwitch

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I am displaying custom text based on a Boolean field from a table in my database.

```
myapp.BrowseAdverts.AdType_postRender = function (element, contentItem) {
    if (contentItem.data.AdType === true) $(element).append("Advert type = BANNER");
    else $(element).append("Advert type = WOW");
};
```

After I edit the selected element from a list (or even add a new item), all the fields will update except for this custom control.

How can I setup the "binding" so the custom text will update when a field is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself:

```
contentItem.dataBind("value", function (value) {
        if (value === true) {
            $(element).text("BANNER");
        } else {
            $(element).text("WOW");
        }
    });
```